# in python how do i automatically transfer specific output data to save on a notepad (.txt file)

Tags: python-2.7

The code is written and the program is running but i need help transferring specific output data from the interactive window onto a text file...

```
print '-'*75
print '\n\t\t\t RECTANGULAR TO POLAR CONVERSION: '
print '-'*75
print '[RECTANGULAR COORDINATES]'
print '\nCoordinates of A:\t\t\tCoordnates of B:\t\t\t'
print format(eastingsa,'.3f'),'mE,',format(northingsa,'.3f'),'mN', '\t\t',format(eastingsb,'.3f'),'mE,',format(northingsb,'.3f'),'mN','\t\t'
print '\n'
print '[POLAR CONVERSION]'
print 'Bearing:\t\t\t\tDistance:'
print degrees,'°',minutes,'\'',seconds,'\"', '\t\t\t',format(distance, '.3f'),'m'
print '-'*75
print '\n\n\n\n'
```

please help...!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste any `print statement` in a text file. This file should be named as `something.py`

But first of all, you will have to enclose every print statement into `""`

like: `print "something"`

then save the file, open up cmd or bash and run the program as follows:

```
python something.py > output.txt
```

where `output.txt` is the file your output will be written.

This is the easiest and sloppiest way to make a script.

for further info, read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/contents.html)